# Ruby on Rails' skip_before_action doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

There are 2 namespaces:

```
api/public
api/mobile
```

Doorkeeper authorization with proper scope is created in public controller. For example:

```
class API::Public::PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action -> { doorkeeper_authorize! :public }

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Controller in mobile namespace is inherited from controller in public namespace. For example:

```
class API::Mobile::PostsController < API::Public::PostsController
  skip_before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
  before_action -> { doorkeeper_authorize! :mobile }
end
```

So the point here is that functionality is same and if there is some difference for mobile then action could be overridden in mobile namespace.
Problem is that scopes are different for those 2 namespaces, but skipping doorkeeper_authorize! doesn't work.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`skip_before_filter` works for skipping methods, not skipping lambdas/procs. Try creating a method for the public authorization:

```
class API::Public::PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_public

  ...

  def authorize_public
    doorkeeper_authorize! :public
  end
end

class API::Mobile::PostsController < API::Public::PostsController
  skip_before_action :authorize_public
  ...
end
```

Comment: If there is method before_action which accepts lambda/proc, why there isn't method for skipping lambda/proc? Is there any constraint?

Comment: How would you specify which lambda/proc to skip? They don't have names. E.g., suppose there were two `before_action` lambdas (as you actually had), and both of them called `doorkeeper_authorize!`. How do you distinguish between them?

Comment: Good point. What about storing lambda in variable? Something like: `authorize_public = lambda { doorkeeper_authorize! :public }`?

And `skip_before_action :authorize_public`

Answer (score 4):

You could call a method within your lambda that returns what to authorize:

```
class API::Public::PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action -> { doorkeeper_authorize! authorization_scope }

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  protected
    def authorization_scope
      :public
    end
end
```

Then your subclasses only need to override the method without getting into a skip_before_filter pain

```
class API::Mobile::PostsController < API::Public::PostsController
  protected
    def authorization_scope
      :mobile
    end
end
```